# Log4J log message once every x seconds?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have code that looks like this:

```
log.info("Entered Loop...");
for(long i = 0; i < LIMIT ; i++) {
    log.info("In loop, iteration " + i);
    doHeavyWork();
}
```

I want the log within the loop to be printed only if the last log message was more than x seconds ago, what is the best way to do that?

Answer (score -2):

If you want to do something repeatedly, you should do it in sepparate thread. See this example:

```
int initialDelay = 30000; // start after 30 seconds
int period = 5000;        // repeat every 5 seconds
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        // job code here
    }
};
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, initialDelay, period);
```

[Source](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=99038)